# Find | parallel executing script with path from find + other arguments

Tags: shell-script, find, gnu-parallel

Due to my lack of Bash knowledge I've tried for a few hours now to get something like this to work:

```
find Directories -mindepth 4 -type d -print0 | parallel -0 -j0 ./MyScript -d {Found Directory} {1} ::: a b c d
```

Where a,b,c and d are different arguments that my script needs to execute commands (in my case being `-rb`, `-s`, `-is 20 44`, `-ib 13 25` .... and so on).

I need to execute the script once per argument for each found subdirectory while keeping the subdirectory information intact. The `-d` tells my script the target directory to execute itself in which works fine if `{1} ::: a b c d` is not there, if it is there then it just runs 4 times with `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` as arguments.

What I have is a large hierarchy of directories, which at depth 4 contains files that the script should execute different commands on based on what the argument `{1}` is.

Since this is a very resource and time consuming script I thought it would be nice to automate it with something like this, but I've clearly misunderstood something completely, anyone who can point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find Directories -mindepth 4 -type d -print0 | parallel -0 -j0 ./MyScript -d {2} {1} ::: a b c d :::: -
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so very much, that works! I ended up trying to put parallels inside parallels which were very slow. One thing though using '-is 20 44' is returning the argument as '-is\ 20\ 44' my futile googling has not nested me a solution to this, my script says they are invalid arguments.